# C++ std::complex<> data type test for NAN, INF (non-convergence)

Tags: c++, math, double, nan

I wish to test whether an operation on a complex number (std::complex) results in a +/- INF or NAN result. (Non-convergent result.)

For example under the mapping z -> z * z + c.

For float or double data types, I believe one can use x != x to test for NAN. I am not sure if this works for +/- INF.

Comment: Something along the lines of `z.abs() > std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`, perhaps?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Will this work or is it a guess? (Useful either way, but would like to be more certain.)

Comment: I'm fairly certain it should work, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: `x-x != 0` will tell you whether you've got something finite or not.  This also works for `complex<float>` and `complex<double>`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: You meant `!(z.abs() > std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`, but note that it's prone to overflow.

Comment: @tmyklebu I meant what I said. How is adding a bang and an unbalanced opening paren supposed to improve matters, exactly?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: If you add the closing parenthesis too, you will not report "finite" for NaN.  Eh, you also need to change the `>` to a `<=`.

Comment: @tmyklebu And if you don't add the closing parentheses, it won't compile. I'm not sure I get your point.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Your code does not do what OP asked and it doesn't come very close.  That's my point.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::isfinite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite). This function returns true if its input is neither `nan` nor `inf`. You can also use `std::isnan` and `std::isinf` to check for those particular properties.

EDIT : For `std::complex`, you can apply the same checks on the `real` and `imag` parts. You could also simply apply it on the `abs` of the `std::complex` object.

Comment: What about for std::complex?

Comment: I suppose one could pass the modulus of the complex number?

Comment: @user3728501 Yes, `abs` would be the safest. If you need to push it a bit more, you could stop with checks on the `real` and `imag` instead.

Comment: @tmyklebu That's because abs() is for integer arguments only I believe. I think it's left in for back-compatibility with older C programs, or for when you just want to clear the sign bit.

Comment: @user3728501: There is an `abs` overload for `complex<T>`  The problem is that there is a finite `complex<double>` whose `abs` is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use this test:

```
std::abs(z) > std::numeric_limits<double>::max()
```

This will fail to detect certain finite complex numbers, such as `complex<double>(DBL_MAX, DBL_MAX)`.  The comparison will also fail for the case where `z` has a NaN component.

`std::isfinite` does not appear to have a complex overload, so you cannot use this test:

```
isfinite(z)
```

You can use this test:

```
z - z != complex<double>(0)
```

If `z` has two finite components, then `z - z` has two zero components and will compare equal to `0`.  If `z` has at least one infinite or NaN component, that component of `z - z` will be NaN.  NaN compares `!=` to everything, including `0` and itself.